# Filter a select statement after datatimepicker

Tags: c#, sql

I have next code C#:

```
cm.CommandText = "Select * from H_Facturi_Clienti where Serie like '" + TextBox1.Text + "%' and Numar like '" + textBox2.Text + "%' and Data >= '"+dateTimePicker1.Text+"'";
```

I know this doesn't work because my datetimepicker is short format: `dd/MM/yyyy` and `Data` in sql is `smalldatetime`: `yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss`

Answer (score 2):

You have a [bad habits to kick](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)  which you try to send `string` to a column which is typed `smalldatetime`.

Send it's `Value` property *directly*, not it's string representation.

But more important, you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

```
using(var con = new SqlConnection(conStr))
using(var cm = con.CreateCommand())
{
   cm.CommandText = @"Select * from H_Facturi_Clienti 
                      where Serie like @serie and Numar like @numar and Data >= @data";
   cm.Parameters.Add("@serie", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text + "%";
   cm.Parameters.Add("@numar", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = textBox2.Text + "%";
   cm.Parameters.Add("@data",  SqlDbType.SmallDateTime).Value = dateTimePicker1.Value;
   // Do whatever you want
}
```

Also `SELECT *` is quite bad. Read [Why is `SELECT *` considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3639861/447156)

As a last thing, `Data` (*ignoring it's case*) could be [reserved keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) in future releases of SQL Server. You *might* wanna use it as `[Data]` but as a best practice, change it to *non*-reserved word.

Comment: Thx a lot. Actually I m new in C# programming language, I'm still learning